# Mostrar graficamente a soma das vendas de vários jogos no mesmo ano

Tags: python, dataframe, gráfico, ciência-de-dados, big-data

Bom, o código abaixo printa na tela a tabela com os valores corretos de quantos jogos foram vendidos globalmente em cada ano de 1980 até 2016. O data base está no github: https://github.com/malegopc/DSBD/tree/main/Datasets/Video_games

Eu gostaria de colocar graficamente esses dados. O código como está printa os anos com os valores certos, mas no gráficos, os valores ficam distintos, errados.[image: Volume de vendas globais por ano (mostrar listagem numérica e gráfico)]

```
Dados2 = df.groupby(by=['Ano'])['Global'].sum()
print(Dados2)

plt.barh(df['Ano'],df['Global'],color = 'green')
plt.subplots_adjust(left=1.5,
                    bottom=3, 
                    right=4.0, 
                    top=5, 
                    wspace=0.2, 
                    hspace=0.9)
plt.xlabel('Global')
plt.ylabel('Ano')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Importando libs e lendo o arquivo do git

```
import pandas as pd 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

url = 'https://github.com/malegopc/DSBD/raw/main/Datasets/Video_games/venda_video_games.xlsx'
df = pd.read_excel(url)
```

Nesse caso o ano não é mais o índice do data frame por causa do parâmetro `as_index=False`

```
df2 = df.groupby(by=['Ano'], as_index=False)['Global'].sum()
```

Creio que você tenha passado o data frame errado, no caso seria o df2:

```
plt.barh(df2['Ano'], df2['Global'], color='green')
plt.subplots_adjust(left=1.5,
                    bottom=3, 
                    right=4.0, 
                    top=5, 
                    wspace=0.2, 
                    hspace=0.9)

plt.yticks(range(df2['Ano'].min(), df2['Ano'].max() + 1))
plt.xlabel('Global')
plt.ylabel('Ano')
plt.show()
```

[image: Grafico]